# Python ATBS Ch 8 Multiclipboard

Tags: python, shell, clipboard, shelve, pyperclip

Hey guys I'm working with this textbook Automate the Boring Stuff and I've made it all the way to chapter 8 with no problems, but I'm having trouble with the Multiclipboard Project. Specifically, how do I start it?

I type `py mcb.pyw save spam` into the python shell but it just says invalid syntax.

Here's the rest of the code to the script.

```
#! python3
# mcb.pyw - Saves and loads pieces of text to the clipboard.
# Usage: py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw list - Loads all keywords to clipboard.
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')

# Save clipboard content.
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
# List keywords and load content.
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword.
```

That is what is listed as the usage command in your code.  If you are on windows you may need to include the .exe for it to work.